# What is the difference between of code written in DrRacket in "R5RS" vs "#lang racket"?

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

Is there a difference between in syntax of coding or code will same in both language types?

I wrote a program in #lang racket language but I was supposed to do it in the "R5RS" type.

Comment: Racket has lots of additional functions that aren't in core Scheme. It also allows you to use square brackets as parentheses.

Comment: There is a large amount of code that make a valid program in both, but they are not the same. Did you encounter any issues when you switched to `#lang r5rs`?

Comment: Racket is derived from R5RS Scheme, and most but not all R5RS programs can be used unaltered with  `#lang racket`. However, Racket is not a strict superset of R5RS Scheme, as there are a number of minor changes in how the language handles string mutability, among other things. More importantly, Racket extends R5RS Scheme in a large number of ways, so going from Racket to R5RS Scheme (or from R6RS Scheme to R5RS Scheme) generally isn't so simple as going the other direction.

Comment: They are 2 different languages, sharing a bit of their kernel -- like `c` vs. `c++`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it depends on the program.

`#lang racket` and `#lang r5rs` share the same basic syntax but smaller things may change between the two, e.g. `[` can be used in place of `(` in racket but not in r5rs.

There may be other differences between the *semantics* or racket and r5rs scheme. This means that the same program may behave differently when running as a racket program or as a r5rs scheme program.

This is usually not the case because both racket and r5rs scheme share a lot of *semantic* but two different implementations of r5rs scheme are allowed to have different semantics in some special and agreed upon cases.

Comment: Racket (#lang racket) descends from R5RS Scheme, but the differences are not small: compare the lists of topics at [The Racket Guide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/index.html) and [Revised5 Report on the Algorithmic Language Scheme](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/)

Answer (score 0):

The most visible difference is in the Dr. Racket REPL. The canonical list in Racket is immutable, while the canonical list in R5RS is mutable. And the REPL treats immutable and mutable lists differently.

In `#lang racket`, the Dr. Racket REPL responds this way (with an immutable list):

```
> '(a b)
'(a b)
```

In `#lang r5rs`, the Dr. Racket REPL responds this way (because mutable lists are displayed by the REPL this way):

```
> '(a b)
(mcons 'a (mcons 'b '()))
```

I believe that is the reason for its different REPL behavior from more typical Schemes. Typical Scheme REPLs respond this way (without the quote in the response):

```
> '(a b)
(a b)
```

Interestingly, with `#lang r5rs`, `display` and `write` behave in Dr. Racket in the expected manner:

```
> (define x '(a b))
> x
(mcons 'a (mcons 'b '()))
> (display '(a b))
(a b)
> (display x)
(a b)
> (write '(a b))
(a b)
> (write x)
(a b)
> x
(mcons 'a (mcons 'b '()))
```